# create a find function to get string between characters

Tags: php, mysql, function, return, substr

(first question posted to Stack)

I'm trying to create a function that:

1. searches a string with a variable value
2. when that variable value is found, it will remove anything before the variable value
3. and it will remove everything after the following pre-determined string

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

    $user_id = '5';
    $week_start = "2014-8-01 00:00:00";                             
    $week_end = "2014-09-01 23:59:59";


    //get the row information
    $result_show_picks = mysql_query("
        SELECT 
        id, uid, pick, date_submitted
        FROM picks_recorded
        WHERE uid = '" . $user_id . "'
        AND date_submitted > '" . $week_start . "'
        AND date_submitted < '" . $week_end . "'
        LIMIT 1
        ", $connection);

        if (!$result_show_picks) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
    }


        while ($row_picks = mysql_fetch_array($result_show_picks)) {
            echo "id = " . $row_picks[id] . "<br />";
            echo "uid = " . $row_picks[uid] . "<br />";
            echo "pick = " . $row_picks[pick] . "<br />";
            echo "date_submitted = " . $row_picks[date_submitted] . "<br />";

            /* this is the output 
                id = 233
                uid = 5
                pick = |1046:648|145:66|1348:736|506:334|97:37|710:434|1421:768|361:257|325:235|698:430|1457:796|1142:694
                date_submitted = 2014-08-18 02:50:00
            */

            $pick_input = $row_picks[pick];
        };

        function assign_values($pick_input) {
            $str1 = ":";
            $str2 = "|";
            $team_picked = substr($pick_input,$str1,$str2);
            return 
                $var1 = value1,
                $var2 = value2,
                $var3 = value3,
                etc, etc;

                /* hoped for return will be (but I have no idea if this is even feasible):
                    $pick_1046 = "648",
                    $pick_145 = "66",
                    $pick_1348 = "736",
                    etc, etc;
                */
        };
    ?>
```

This is how I want to use it:

```
    <?php 
        if($row['this_games_id'] == $pick_1046){
            echo "yes";
        };
    ?>
```

I hope this makes sense. In case it matters, this is a football picks site that is just for friends and does not have gambling of any sort involved.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Preform the below on each of the strings you want to get information from and you get whatever is between `%start%` and `%end%`.

```
$start = '%start%';
$end   = '%end%';

$long_string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.%start%I want this text%end% Tempore quae explicabo tempora eum aspernatur harum, rem itaque cumque ipsum neque!';

$pos1 = (stripos($long_string, $start) + strlen($start));
$pos2 = (stripos($long_string, $end));

$result = substr($long_string, $pos1, ($pos2 - strlen($long_string)));

echo $result;
```